# how browsers clean the cache when the cache reach the limit?

Tags: http, caching, browser, lru

I tried to look for this information on the net, but couldn't find good info about that.
Do you know to describe how it works?
1. Is it some kind of LRU algorithm?
2. Does all the browsers share the same "cleaning algorithm?

Thanks!
Shay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers simply works with LRU mechanism and throws the "old" pages.